# Lodash equals and omit not working properly

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have 2 JSON objects and I have to check if there are any changes to them.

They are identical but this property is not, so the _.equals returns false so they are not equal

1rst Object:

```
this.board['children'] = [
    {
        ...
        isSelected: true
        ...
    },
    
    {
        ...
        isSelected: false
        ...
    }
];
```

2nd Object:

```
odataElement['children'] = [
    {
        ...
        isSelected: false
        ...
    },
    
    {
        ...
        isSelected: false
        ...
    }
]
```

So I've tried this function to omit the isSelected property:

```
var result = _.isEqualWith(this.board['children'], odataElement['children'], this.customizer);

customizer = function (objValue, othValue) {
    let arrayOfEquals = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < objValue.length; i++) {
        arrayOfEquals.push(
            _.isEqual(
                _.omit(objValue[i], ['isSelected']),
                _.omit(othValue[i], ['isSelected'])
            )
        );
    }
    return !_.includes(arrayOfEquals, false) ? true : false;
}
```

But it seems that it doesn't omit the isSelected property and is always false.

Any hints? Thanks!

Comment: `this.board['children']` is object or array?

Comment: Please include actual arrays of objects.

Comment: is an array of objects!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `_.isEqualWith()` and ignore this key by always returning `true`:

```js
const boardChildren = [{ isSelected: true }, { isSelected: false }]
const odataElementChildren = [{ isSelected: false }, { isSelected: false }]

const result = _.isEqualWith(boardChildren, odataElementChildren, (v1, v2, key) => key === 'isSelected' ? true : undefined)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```